# Find all cycles through a given vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs, enumeration

Given a directed graph $G$ and a vertex $v$, how can we enumerate all simple cycles that pass through $v$?

I found a question that describes [how to enumerate all simple cycles in $G$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7216/755), but I want only the cycles that pass through $v$, so this question is a bit different.  The total number of cycles in $G$ can be exponentially larger than the number of cycles passing through $v$, so just enumerating all cycles in $G$ and keeping only those that go through $v$ might be inefficient.

I'm not asking to *count* the number of cycles; I want an algorithm to *list* them all. I would like an [output-sensitive algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm), where the running time is some low-order polynomial of the number of cycles that go through $v$.  I know there can be exponentially many cycles, so there is no hope for an algorithm whose running time is polynomial in the size of the graph.

Motivation: This is a cleaned-up version of [Given a directed graph and a vertex v, find all cycles that go through v?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60386/755).  I wanted to ask the more general version of the question.

Comment: Can't you compute a cycle basis for the graph and use that? I know the concept of a cycle basis extends to directed graphs, but I don't know details. [Here is a survey](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/SurveyCycleBases.pdf)

Comment: @adrianN, cool, thanks!  Unfortunately that seems to only work for undirected graphs.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution: Modify Johnson's algorithm

Johnson's algorithm can be used to enumerate all cycles in $G$.  It can be easily modified to enumerate only and all the cycles that contain $v$.

Johnson's algorithm works by numbering the vertices from $1$ to $n$, and classifying each cycle according to the smallest-numbered vertex in the cycle.  It first enumerate all cycles whose smallest-numbered vertex is $1$, then all whose smallest-numbered vertex is $2$, and so on.

So, here is the modification to Johnson's algorithm.  Choose a vertex numbering where $v$ receives the number $1$, and the other vertices are numbered in any order.  Run Johnson's algorithm, but only enumerate the cycles whose smallest-numbered vertex is $1$.  This will enumerate all the cycles containing $v$, and only the cycles containing $v$.

### Running time

The running time of this algorithm is $O((m+n)(q+1))$, where $q$ is the total number of cycles containing $v$, $n$ is the number of vertices, and $m$ is the number of edges.  Its space consumption is $O(n+m)$.

### References

Here is a full citation to Johnson's paper describing the algorithm:

[Finding all the elementary circuits of a directed graph][1]. Donald B. Johnson. SIAM J. COMPUT. Vol. 4, No. 1, March 1975

See also [Find the Simple Cycles in a Directed Graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7216/755).  For help understanding Johnson's algorithm, see

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908575/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2939877/781723
- [What is the difference in 'logical array blocked' and array list B, and what do they represent?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58180/755)

For pointers to implementations of Johnson's algorithm and discussion of other algorithms to find all cycles in a graph, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/546655/781723.  I don't know if there's a way to modify them to enumerate only cycles that contain $v$.